# How can I increase the expiry time of a Firebase token?

Tags: php, wordpress, firebase, firebase-authentication

Does anyone know to increase the expiry time of a Firebase token? I am using Firebase/php-jwt. Following the [custom token generation documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). When I increase the time beyond 3600, the token becomes invalid. Can anyone help me please?

```
$now_seconds = time();
$payload = array(
"iss" => $service_account_email,
"sub" => $service_account_email,
"aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
"iat" => $now_seconds,
"exp" => $now_seconds+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
"uid" => $uid,
"claims" => array(
  "premium_account" => $is_premium_account
)
);
return JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, "RS256");
```

Comment: you need to sign with signInWithCustomToken() method to have the token with higher expiry time (until session time out / user manually log out)

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentationon creating custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library):

> `exp`- Expiration time
>
> The time, in seconds since the UNIX epoch, at which the token
>   expires. **It can be a maximum of 3600 seconds later than the `iat`.**

There is currently no way to use a longer expiration period on Firebase Authentication ID tokens.